# Vertical centering: what's the difference between grid and flex method?

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, css-grid, centering

There are two ways to vertically center contents with the introduction of flex box.

The first is:

```
.is-vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

The other is:

```
.is-vertical-center {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center center;
}
```

Visually, both look the same. What are actual differences between the two?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids

Comment: one is done by grid and the other by flexbox, this is the difference

Comment: Your question doesn't really show any differences. `align-items` currently applies to flex and grid containers, and eventually will apply to all elements. The same could be said for `place-items`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you're correct. In this limited test case, the result is visually identical. Both allow for easy-to-implement (and, just as importantly, *predictable* and predictably-*spaced*) layouts. But there are significant differences between the applicability of one approach vs the other. Perhaps more than you're after, but...

**One vs Two Dimensions**

The main difference between the css `flexbox` (or the Flexible Box Layout Module) specification and the css `grid` specification is that the former (`flexbox`) is one dimensional, while the latter (`grid`) is two dimensional.

In other words, `flexbox` is intended to enable easy layout of items in a single direction: horizontally (in a row) or vertically (in a column).

`grid`, on the other hand, allows for layouts that require (or could benefit from) both horizontal *and* vertical specification: rows *and* columns.

**Content-first vs. Layout-first**

Per Harald Borgen [suggests](https://hackernoon.com/the-ultimate-css-battle-grid-vs-flexbox-d40da0449faf) that another key difference between the two is that `flexbox` is a content-first spec, while grid is a layout-first spec. In other words, `flexbox` doesn't require much up-front layout definition to do its thing. Slap the `dispay: flex` rule on your flex parent and `flexbox` decides how to lay things out (in a predictable, sane manner, of course). Yes, the results are tweakable by adding different properties, but `flexbox` does a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Placement of content is *fluid*.

`grid` is a bit different in this regard. You will generally need to define your, well, grid when you first implement your layout. How many columns do you require? You need to let `grid` know. What content needs to go in which layout "cell?" `grid` cares. `flexbox` on the other hand, because it cares only about one dimension, can take more liberties with spacing and placement of content. With `grid`, the placement of content is *fixed*.

Rachel Andrew, a grid expert if ever there was one, makes a similar distinction but labels it:

> Working from the content out [`flexbox`] vs. working from the Grid definition in [`grid`]

**Browser Support**

Another salient difference (at least as this is being written in early 2019) is that browser support for `flexbox` (especially with the addition of [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to a front-end build process) is excellent (supporting back to IE11 [or even IE10] is a fairly trivial task, even though those browsers implement older, "tweener" syntaxes that are now outdated).

On the other hand, while browser support for `grid` is nothing short of [pretty darn good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid), supporting a grid layout back to IE11 (if that's important to you) can be a bit hairy for anything other than simple scenarios (see Rachel Andrew's [excellent article](https://www.rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/)). As for IE10, don't bother. For this reason, some devs will "hack" flexbox to accomplish layouts that are probably better served by using the `grid` specification. No judgment here.

**A tangent**

([Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/), for example, is something of a barometer of what's currently cross-browser compatible back to IE10: notably, it does implement a `flex`-powered layout system (while citing the need for vendor-specific prefixing) but does *not* implement `grid`. That doesn't mean `grid` lacks broad support—as noted above, support is *good*—nor should that fact deter one from implementing a `grid`-powered layout; it's just an interesting data point.)

So, to circle back around to your question: What's the difference? Visually, nothing (in this particular case). Strategically, quite a bit.

A handy article from Rachel Andrew for distinguishing use cases: https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/03/30/should-i-use-grid-or-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you. This is the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

As SLaks mention before:

*'Flexbox is a one-dimensional layout method for laying out items in rows or columns.'*

- So you could use it to manage listings such a products layout. You're coding the behavior for every product.

*'CSS Grid Layout is a two-dimensional layout system for the web.'*

- Is useful when you want to define the position of fixed elements on your webpage, as header, body, footer. Every child has a defined position.